# Self made variable not working in python

Tags: python

Hey everyone i'm abit of a noob when it comes to python and i was playing around with an unfinished mark to grade converter i had started in class. Everything works fine up until 'if second == yes:' where it says that yes in undefined. How do i solve this?!?!?! Again i'm a noob and i thought that this website would be the easiest place to get an answer(aside from school but i cba). Thanks for any help!

```
print("-------WELCOME-------")

testscore = int(input("What mark did you get?"))

if testscore> 75:
    print("You got an A!")
else:
    if testscore< 30:
        print("You got an F")

second = input("do you want to get another test score?")
if second == yes:
    if testscore> 75:
        print("You got an A!")
else:
    if testscore< 30:
        print("You got an F")
if second == no:
    print("Thanks for using MARK TO GRADE CONVERTER. See you soon!")
```

Comment: `if second == "yes":` ... compare with the string "yes", not a variable yes.

Comment: `if second == 'yes':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it in quotes:

```
if second == "yes":
```

As is, you aren't comparing the strings, you're checking to see if `second` is equal to a variable called `yes` which doesn't exist.